# How to implement keyword specific page invocation using PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to implement keyword specific page invocation using PHP codeigniter

[Binary search Tree Implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498487/binary-search-tree-implementaion)

for e.g. in above URL keyword "binary-search-tree-implementaion" is method name or parameter for specific controller. because most of things are dynamic then how web site is going to manage all those things?

I want to implement it for my web site like this

http://example.com/search/digital-camera-price-in-india

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but usually a URI structure like `/search/digital-camera-price-in-india` would route to the `Search` controller and `digitalCameraPriceInIndia` action.

```
/search/digital-camera-price-in-india

=> SearchController::digitalCameraPriceInIndiaAction()
```

If you want to route similar URIs (different products for example) to a catch-all method, you've have to setup custom routing.

The CodeIgniter documentation for routing [is here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: i don't to create methods for each query string it should be virtual

Answer (score 0):

As per @chriso's answer you will need to set up a custom route to achieve this as by default the uri structure is /controller/action/params.  So in your config/routes.php file you can add something like:

> $route['search/(:any)'] =
>   "search/some_action";

And then use the relevant uri segment (

> $this->uri->segment[1]

I think) as your search parameter.

Answer (score 0):

if you set up your route like this:

```
$route['^search/(:any)'] = "search/my_controller_function/$1";
```

Then you can just write your function like this:

```
public function my_controller_function($search_input) 
{
 // your code here
}
```